# Debug Rust Cloudflare workers in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am experimenting with Rust Cloudflare workers as described here:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/workers-rust-sdk/

It is great that we can debug the workers locally as described in:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/debugging-workers/

However, I didn't manage to run the worker in IntelliJ so that I could use breakpoints and watches like in regular Rust code in IntelliJ?

Comment: any news about this?

Comment: i even can not see any lint information in clion.